# Load testing Rest services

Tags: load, load-testing, gatling

I am trying to figure out a strategy for load testing of my Rest services. These services processes request asynchronously. They took a dumpId and dumpUrl in query parameter and return Status 200 immediately. And then process data asynchronously and dump data on provided dumpUrl. We can query the status of dump using dumpId on dumpUrl status query end point.

My question is what should be the best strategy for load testing of such service. We started with gattling script, but seems it is not feasible with gattling framework.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure regarding Gatling, but in case of [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) the scenario would look like:

- [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to measure the total time

  - [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to send the initial request
  - [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) to loop the nested request(s) until expected dump status will be returned

    - [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to do the polling

You can extract the values from responses using [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) if required.

References:

- [JMeter: Getting Started](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)
- [Apache JMeter Training Academy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/learn-jmeter-for-free-launching-the-jmeter-academy)